# How can I type a path in Unity's Open File dialog?

Tags: unity

Instead of the usual "select a location from what you see", I need to type a path to reach a file a I need to open.

Where can I type locations (paths) in this dialog?

[image: Open file dialog screenshot]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to switch to address-bar from the "path-bar" (and vice versa).

Comment: a few days later, same need of entering a path. Completly forget  the Ctrl+L shortcut. Adding a tip inside that dialog would be really appreciated :)

Comment: Base on this https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/938 making that hard to find is a "feature"; the GTK owners think they get to decide how you should want to use apps that use GTK.